# WCAG 2.0 Criteria 1.4.1 / 2.1.1

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag2.0

I'm in trouble with WCAG validation, I try to use this checker fro the first time.

In the script tags I've the a potential problem

> script may use color alone

and

> Make all functionality available from a keyboard

but I really  can't understand how to fix this

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My web page</title>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
     <body class="nav-md">
        <div>text</div> 
     </body>
   </html>
```

I'm using achecker.ca

Answer (score 0):

> I try to use this checker fro the first time.

The problems are listed as "potential problems". This mean that they are simple warnings asking you to do manual check.

See [Does a script tag really need a color defined?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88444/does-a-script-tag-really-need-a-color-defined) to understand more about this non-issue.